# Store temporarily custom windows authentication roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication

I have a MVC4 project in which I implemented custom windows authentication following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018222/extending-windows-authentication-in-asp-net-mvc-3-application).

Everything is working fine, I created my roles database and so on. The thing is that I want to store temporarily the roles into Session Variable because almost every controller's action have an Authentication Attribute so every authentication request would hit the database, and I don't want that.

All the magic happens in Application_AuthenticateRequest

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            WindowsIdentity wi = (WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
            CustomPrincipal mp = new CustomPrincipal(wi);
            HttpContext.Current.User = mp;
        }

    }
```

In that event HttpContext.Session is not available (yet) but every request hit this event before anything else.

I want to store the roles session based, Is there a way to do that or I have to implement authentication cookie in order to achieve that?

Thank you!